# Different Android devices give different accelerometer sensor values on same movement?

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, hardware-acceleration

I have 2-3 different company devices (Asus, moto, 1+, etc) there I have used linear accelerometer Android sensor but when I move (vertically) these devices at same time with same force the values of event changes for all devices. Values are different, and the difference is too much.

Example:

- moto it is 4, 5, 7, 8... etc
- Asus it is 8, 9, 11, 12... etc
- 1+ it is 4, 4.5, 6, 8... etc

So why is this and how to calibrate accelerometer to get similar values?

Comment: How are you "moving them with the same force"?  That's very difficult to do correctly without machines, and even then is easy to screw up.  The best calibration for them is to make sure that on a perfectly level surface at rest that the acceleration is 9.8 m/s^2 straight down.

Comment: Put all the devices on a hard board and move that board up and down.And for more information I am using liner accelerometer on perfectly  level surface these devices give different values also.

Comment: Straight up and down?  If there's rotation involved the torque would cause the actual acceleration on the ones furthest from the axis of rotation to see more acceleration.  Although if that's your setup you've probably thought of that.

Comment: But its gives different values on same perfectly level surface ?

Comment: Also looking at your numbers-  moto and +1 seem fairly close-  its the Asus that's out of whack with the others.  Do you have access to a 2nd Asus to test if its just that particular unit?

Comment: Also I see other reports of issues with the accelerometer in some Asus devices:  http://www.asus.com/zentalk/in/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=26004